# cocos2d tap disabled when leaderboard closed on game center

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I show the game center leaderboard but when I tap the done button the leaderboard close.
But I can't tap on any buttons on the screen.

Here my code :

```
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    CCLOG(@"leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish %@", viewController);
    [viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [viewController release];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

Cocos2D 2.0

```
-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Cocos2D 1.0

```
-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using cocos2D 1.0

I'm sorry but the code you provide doesn't work.

I fixed the problem. I just comment one line.
I lost the close animation of the leaderboard but it's work.

```
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    CCLOG(@"leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish %@", viewController);
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [viewController release];    
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}
```